# R twitter search: simplifying searches to reduce redundancy

Tags: r

I have developed a function to search twitter using geocodes from the searchTwitter function in twitteR. I am looking to download all tweets sent within a distance of a given location. To make sure I get all tweets I search for vowels (a,e,i,o,u) and then comma "," and period ".". I of course get duplicates of the tweets which I then remove outside of the function. This strikes me as a cumbersome way of doing the search as I am calling the search 7 times.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of doing it that does not have so much redundancy in the searchTwitter call?

Here is my function:

```
download_tweets<-function(loc, range,srch_st){
 if (loc=="brisbane") {lat=-27.470506
                      lon=153.022957
                      gc<-paste(lat,",",lon,",",range,"km",sep="")
 } 
  if (loc=="tvl") {lat=-19.286119
                    lon=146.796374
                    gc<-paste(lat,",",lon,",",range,"km",sep="")
                  } 

  if (loc=="cairns") {lat=-16.918881
                      lon=145.764427
                     gc<-paste(lat,",",lon,",",range,"km",sep="")
                    } 

  for (i in 1:nrow(srch_st)){findit<-paste(loc,"_",srch_st[i,"alt"],sep="")
                                x<-searchTwitter(as.character(srch_st[i,"srch"]), n=15000,geocode=gc)
                               if (length(x)>0) {x<-twListToDF(x)
                                                x<-unique(x)
                                                x$srch<-findit
                                if (!exists("dat")) {dat<-x} else     {dat<-rbind(dat,x)}
                               }
 }
  dat$loc<-loc
  return(dat)
}

tvl_aa<-download_tweets(loc="tvl", range=30,srch_st)
tvl_aa<-tvl_aa[-which(duplicated(tvl_aa$text)),]
```

The different searches are identifying non-duplicate tweets:

```
 table(tvl_aa$srch)

 tvl_a  tvl_e  tvl_i tvl_pd 
 27      1     36    535
```

There must be more efficient (and elegant?) ways of doing it? I have tried searching using a list of terms but could not get that to work and it would not solve the redundancy problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something to help you extract vowels using the `%in%` function. You should only have to make one call for tweets, I think.

```
text <- c("I hope that, and I really mean this, that this example helps.")

split <- tolower(strsplit(text, "")[[1]])
chars <- subset(split, split %in% c("a","e","i","o","u",".",","))

table(chars)
```

Output:

```
chars
, . a e i o 
2 1 6 6 4 1
```

I also hear that `grep` is useful.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for your suggestion. I am probably being slow today but it is not the distribution of vowels that I am looking for. I want to download the whole tweet. The reason I need the vowels is to use as a search for all tweets in a location - to act as a wild card. Usually people search with a text string like "climate" and get everything with climate in it. I want everything, all tweets. I thought that most tweets should have either a vowel, period or comma in it so if I search for these I should get all tweets. I am probably just missing what you're suggesting. Sorry, can you clarify?